# CoTURN: STUN works, but TURN does not work

Tags: networking, webrtc, stun, turn, coturn

I try config CoTURN now, but i have some problems.

With STUN i have not troubles, bun when i test TURN, i get an error in browser: "ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details".

Now i want test anonymous TURN. My configs are:

```
listening-port=3478    
min-port=49152
max-port=49200
no-auth
log-file=/var/tmp/turn.log
no-stun
```

My peer configs in js:

```
var peerConf = {
    'iceServers': [
        {
            "url": "stun:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3478"
        },
        {
            "url": "turn:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3478?transport=tcp",
            "credential": 'abcd',
            "username": 'abcd'
        },
        {
            "url": "turn:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3478?transport=udp",
            "credential": 'abcd',
            "username": 'abcd'
        }]
};
```

Log return me this:

```
285: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote addr bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:49920
285: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
285: IPv4. Local relay addr: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:49180
285: session 001000000000000001: new, realm=<>, username=<>, lifetime=10
285: session 001000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
285: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote addr bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:49921
285: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
285: IPv4. Local relay addr: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:49183
285: session 002000000000000001: new, realm=<>, username=<>, lifetime=10
285: session 002000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
285: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
285: IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:53133
285: IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:53132
285: IPv4. Local relay addr: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:49168
285: session 001000000000000002: new, realm=<>, username=<>, lifetime=10
285: session 001000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
285: IPv4. Local relay addr: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:49191
285: session 001000000000000003: new, realm=<>, username=<>, lifetime=10
285: session 001000000000000003: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
285: session 001000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
285: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
285: session 002000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
285: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
285: session 001000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
285: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
285: session 002000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
286: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
286: session 001000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
286: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
286: session 002000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
287: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
287: session 001000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
287: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
287: session 002000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
288: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
288: session 001000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
288: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
288: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote addr ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:47718
288: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
288: IPv4. Local relay addr: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:49187
288: session 003000000000000001: new, realm=<>, username=<>, lifetime=600
288: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
288: session 002000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
288: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
288: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
288: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
288: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
289: IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:35396
289: IPv4. Local relay addr: aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:49166
289: session 003000000000000002: new, realm=<>, username=<>, lifetime=600
289: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
289: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
289: IPv4. tcp or tls connected to: ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:35397
289: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
289: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
289: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
289: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
290: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
290: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
290: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
291: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
291: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
291: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
291: session 001000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
291: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
292: session 002000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
292: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
293: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
293: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
293: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
294: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
294: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
295: session 001000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:49920, reason: allocation timeout
295: session 001000000000000001: delete: realm=<>, username=<>
295: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
295: session 002000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:49921, reason: allocation timeout
295: session 002000000000000001: delete: realm=<>, username=<>
295: session 001000000000000002: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:53133, reason: allocation timeout
295: session 001000000000000002: delete: realm=<>, username=<>
295: session 001000000000000003: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb:53132, reason: allocation timeout
295: session 001000000000000003: delete: realm=<>, username=<>
296: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
296: session 003000000000000001: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
297: session 003000000000000002: realm <> user <>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
298: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
298: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
298: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
298: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
298: session 003000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:47718, reason: allocation timeout
298: session 003000000000000001: delete: realm=<>, username=<>
299: session 003000000000000002: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:35396, reason: allocation timeout
299: session 003000000000000002: delete: realm=<>, username=<>
299: session 002000000000000002: TCP socket closed remotely ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:35397
299: session 002000000000000002: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:35397, reason: TCP connection closed by client (callback)
299: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote addr ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:47718
299: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
301: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
302: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
328: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
329: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
331: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
333: handle_turn_command: STUN method 0x1 ignored
359: session 003000000000000003: closed (2nd stage), user <> realm <> origin <>, local aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa:3478, remote ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc:47718, reason: allocation watchdog determined stale session state
```

Help me, please. What mistake I made?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35452566/7006485. In my confs missing 'realm' parameter.